# Variable passed into .on() function always is the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sort of emulating Backbone's event system with an object like this:

```
var events = {
    'click .one': 'fnOne',
    'click .two': 'fnTwo',
    'click .three': 'fnThree'
}
```

Then to set the event listeners with jquery I'm using the following:

```
var method,
    match,
    event_name,
    selector;

var scope = {
     // Complex object literal passed to the event's
     // function for access...
};

var delegateEventSplitter = /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/;
for (key in events) {
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        method = events[key];
        match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
        event_name = match[1];
        selector = match[2];

        $('#element').on(event_name,selector,function(event){ 
            method(event,scope);
        });
     }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it's binding correctly except all of the events fire the last function `fnThree`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a closure/loop problem. A closure only binds lexical names, not the values at the time.

One of my favorite ways to capture values is `with`:

```
for (key in events) {
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        method = events[key];
        match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
        event_name = match[1];
        selector = match[2];

        with ({method:method})
        {
            $('#element').on(event_name,selector,function(event){ 
               method(event,scope);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But this causes some acolytes of Doug Crockford to die of heart attack so you can also do:

```
            (function(method) { $('#element').on(event_name,selector,function(event){ 
               method(event,scope);
            }); })(method);
```

I'll let you decide which you find preferable.

Comment: +1 for the really nice usage of the `with()` method ... even though some might consider it deprecated

Comment: It occurs to me you can also do `with {method:events[key]}` to be even more concise. Same with the self-calling closure, you can pass `events[key]` as the argument.

Comment: I went with the IFFE, don't want to piss off the Crock-alytes :-)

Comment: Don't want to ruin the party, but even Brendan Eich said that `with` is one of the big mistakes in JavaScript. Using it will throw an error in strict mode. So it's much more than just "convention" to not use it.

Comment: *Assigning* in `with` when wrapped on an arbitrary dynamic object with unknown lexical capture is the problem. Using an object literal on `with` is similar to using the ECMAScript Harmony's upcoming `let`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.each()`. It's function argument conveniently forms a closure at each iteration.

```
$.each(events, function(key, method) {
    var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
    $('#element').on(match[1], match[2], function(event){ 
        method(event, scope);
    });
});
```